# How to set a ImageView in a layout of which some portion is in same layout and rest outside the layout

Tags: android

I want to place the imageview in a layout so that it some portion is visible in same layout and rest should be visible outside it and over other layout.

**activity main**

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top"
sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#c4fff8"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#ffd8b1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/edittext_layout"
android:layout_height="250dp">

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cat1"
android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView6"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

**edittext layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<stroke android:color="#050505"
android:width="1dp"></stroke>
<solid android:color="#80a7a7a7"/>
</shape>
```

In this app, i want to pull down the layout like the notification pulldown and there will be a image in the layout which will be half visible in the main screen layout, or we can say that its is over the main layout and rest will be in its parent layout. How can i set image like this, guyz help me out.

Thank You In Advance

**Importing the Library**

```
dependencies {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
}
```

The dependency has been taken from the Github,https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P7lH.png) I want layout arrangement like this but with this dependency ,framelayout will not work.

Comment: can you add screen shot how exactly your need is?

Comment: You cant have an imageview with two parent layouts

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshot check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot actually place a View on 2 layouts.
If you just want to the imageView to look as if it is above two layouts you can very well use FrameLayout where you can have the imageview positioned over those layouts.

But there is no way you can have a view with 2 parent layouts.

Comment: we can't use frame layout with this dependency, and it can have only two children. Try it and if done then post the code here.